# Merging two text files gives wierd results

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

I need to merge two text files by putting them in a vector array and then writing them in a new text file.
After merging them.The new file has extra characters.

FE:

```
f1.txt ("text1")
f2.txt ("text2.")
f12.txt ("text1˙text2.˙W64")
```

Content of the buffer: "text1 text2. W64"

Here is the code:

```
int main(){
       enum errorcode{FNF,FNC};
       vector<char> buffer;
       char ime[255];
       cin>>ime;//first file
       ifstream ud1(ime,ios::in);
       if(ud1.is_open()){
                        while(!ud1.eof())buffer.push_back(ud1.get());
                        ud1.close();
                        }
       else {cout<<"File not found.";return FNF;}
       cin>>ime;//second file
       ifstream ud2(ime,ios::in);
       if(ud2.is_open()){
                         while(!ud2.eof())buffer.push_back(ud2.get());
                         ud2.close();
                         }
       else {cout<<"File not found.";return FNF;}
       cin>>ime;//new file
       ofstream id(ime,ios::out);
       if(id.is_open()){
                        for(int i=0;i<buffer.capacity();i++)id.put(buffer[i]);
                        id.close();
                        }
       else {cout<<"File not created.";return FNC;}
       return 0;

       }
```

I guess this is because of notepad or files themselves.
Can you please tell me reason for this.

Comment: I think `id << ud1.rdbuf() << ud2.rdbuf();` after validating all three files opened successfully would shorten this up quite a bit. And regardless, using `.eof()` id your loop conditions [**is wrong**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

you are using [Vector capacity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/): Returns the size of the storage space currently allocated for the vector, expressed in terms of elements.

You must use [vector size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/): Returns the number of elements in the vector. This is the number of actual objects held in the vector, which is not necessarily equal to its storage capacity.

**About the ˙**

please look at [istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) return value:

**Return Value**

*The first signature returns the character read, or the end-of-file value (EOF) if no characters are available in the stream (note that in this case, the failbit flag is also set).*

So, you could change the loop to this:

```
while(!ud1.eof()){
    int tmpChar = ud1.get();
    if( !ud1.eof() )
        buffer.push_back(tmpChar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the imput. After changing capacity to size, the W64 is gone but ˙ remain between and at the end od texts.